# What does chromosome CHR_Un, CHR_MT in the ftp site of NCBI mean?

Tags: genetics, chromosome, database

I am not a biologist. But need some genetic data. So I searched internet and reached NCBI's website. I came to know from the FAQ page that I can the complete genome data of organisms from ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/. So I went to the FTP site and opened the homosapien section ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/H_sapiens/. I found folders CHR_1 to CHR_22, CHR_MT,CHR_Un, CHR_X and CHR_Y.

My doubt is this : Normally there are only 23 pair chromosomes right? 1 to 22 pairs OK. XY make another pair. Then what are MT and Un ?

And the folder which I am looking is a genome of male right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**chr_MT**: List of variations that map to the mitochondria

**chr_Multi.txt.gz**: List of variations that map to multiple chromosomes

**chr_UN**: List of mapped variations that are on unplaced chromosomes

see [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK174586/) for more information.

This is the reference genome for human, as far as I know there is no discrimination for it into male/female.

Comment: If it was female genome , do we have to consider X twice.

Comment: @terdon : Do you mean the AGTC sequences as 'List of variations'?

Comment: @dexterdev I did not answer this, Chris did. I just edited which is why you see my name there. I don't know what Chris meant by that since I can't find that file on the FTP site nor see it mentioned in the FTP's [README](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/H_sapiens/README) (which, by the way, you should read).

Comment: OK @terdon I will read it.

Comment: @dexterdev "List of variations" simply means variations from the reference sequence.

Comment: @Chris I will have read more to understand these. For example what is the "reference sequence" here then?

Comment: The reference sequence is the sequence of a genome which is considered to be the "normal" sequence of this species. This varies from individual to individual due to a individual set of insertions, deletions, polymorphism and so on.